# Python - How to exclude a process if a string is missing

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello everyone I am new to this place and new to Python as well.
I have been working on a program and is a bit stuck.
I have a lot of .txt and they looks something like this

```
# "name" "number1" "number2" "number3"
```

These .txt provide information that allows me to draw a chart.
I have got the codes for drawing a chart etc.
All I want to do is exclude those .txt that do not have either/both "number2" and "number3"
Is there any code allow me to do so?
I have already broke the string

```
# "name" "number1" "number2" "number3"
```

down by space by using split()

Comment: Can you check the length of the broken up string (presumably stored as a list)?

Comment: How can I do it? Coz I am new to python so I dont know a lot of the commands :/

Comment: If you have the string `a="name number1 number2 number3"`, you can check the number of fields by `num_fields = len(a.split())` which in this case is 4.

Comment: Right, I think it will work! I am going to try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines in the `.txt` are as written, than this will work:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if len(line.split()) == 5:
            #do something- these lines are the right length (assuming the line includes the '#' sign)
```

Comment: This is how I do it! After I got the number of fields I did that and I am letting the program run see if it works. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, a basic python test like `if "number2" in line_split and "number3" in line_split` should be good.

Comment: This will only work if `"number2"` and `"number3"` are exactly that- it sounds like there will be different data on each line.

Comment: Matthew is right, each .txt have a differe "number 2" and "number 3"